# configure dhcp server in Ubuntu 13.10 and other version?

Tags: server, 13.10, dhcp

salam (Hi)

What is the difference between install / configure dhcp-server in Ubuntu 13.10 and other versions?

I see a video about configure dhcp-server in Ubuntu 12 but I can't configure it in Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: What dhcp server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

i recommend you to use simple dns/dhcp server DNSMASQ from ubuntu repository

Comment: +1 `dnsmasq` is the right choice for a home network, easy to setup and  maintain.

Comment: i'm use dnsmasq in network with 200+ stations. Working well.

Comment: Yes i guess :) But for complex DNS management other solutions are better(imho).

Comment: Yes, for DNS, you right, but i'm using DHCP only.

Comment: i ask about difference between config dhcp server in 13.10 and other version!!!

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer

Install means to copy the files needed to run an application into the right folders, making the necessary changes needed by the application.

Configure means to change the settings of an application that is installed on your system to suit the user/system preferences for it to run properly.

In your case would be to get DHCP server loaded to the system, getting it to the right locations, and then configuring it by setting up the correct network preferences, to suit your needs and particular configuration for it to work properly.